# how to call a function after a time during running main function in C#

Tags: c#, timer, async-await

I have some code in main function, and I want to interrupt main function by calling another function like `foo` after a random time (100 ms for example). How to I can do this ?
for example see below:

```
void main()
{
    intsruction 1;
    intsruction 2;
    intsruction 3;// for example if 100 ms ends after executing instruction 
                  //3 the foo function should call after it, and after executing
                  //foo function, returns here and execute instruction 4
    intsruction 4;
    intsruction 5;
    intsruction 6;
}
```

the foo function :

```
void foo()
{
    instruction 7;
}
```

After complete execution, the flow of program can be :

```
 intsruction 1;
 intsruction 2;
 intsruction 3;
 intsruction 7;// foo
 intsruction 4;
 intsruction 5;
 intsruction 6;
```

Comment: More details, please. Interrupt means block? Wait for 100 ms inside foo or before launching foo?

Comment: Any example of your code could help understand your question better.

Comment: Who calls `foo()`? What architecture (winforms, console, wpf, webforms) ? Depending on what you trying to do see `Timer`, `Thread`/`Task` or `BackgroundWorker`. Async thingies may also work, but it's hard to tell what is the best without knowing details.

Comment: @Sinatr:foo calls automatically after a time. winforms or console.it is not important

Comment: Then `foo` can be a timer event, while `main()` code runs in parallel (by using `Task`). Architecture is important, because you can't really *wait* in UI thread, unless it's console (no UI and you don't need user input right away). Do such in winforms and you are doomed. From other point of view, `BackgroundWorker` is an easy to start learning multi-threading tool, but it is not working for console application.

Answer (score 1):

You can not just "interrupt" main at some point, and run your code, after 100ms.  What you *can* do, instead, is to run the code you are interested in after 100ms (using, say, `System.Timers.Timer`). 
After, if the reason of suspending the main thread is dependency between those at some point, in *that* point check for both results: *main* and *timers* and make appropriate choices.  That is called *speculative execution*, where you run both cases of your hypothetical `if` branch, and *after* pick the appropriate result. Note: That technique is commonly used in parallel computing.

Comment: Note that `a `Timer` cannot run some code in *precisely* 100ms.  It's precision is quite a bit larger than 1 ms.  You can run some code in *approximately* 100ms.

Comment: @Servy: correct, the term "precisely" is not "technically accurate", will change to something more realistic...

Answer (score 0):

Or better yet you can use Reactive Extensions and stop worrying about interrupts.  With Rx you can set up a totally decoupled timed push of data per your requirements, the client which would be notified (your program) merely sets up a subscription to the Observable.   Your code would look similar to this:

```
 TheDataDesired.Subscribe(p=>{
      //the variable p now has the data.
 });
```

It's similar to event handling, but in some respects nicer, as the data is already marshalled onto the thread of the subscriber. Add to that the extensive support for LINQ and you have a very nice decoupled way of getting data by just waiting for it to arrive.  Now it doesn't just have to be data, it could be anything including processing of events on the system.

Our good friend Lee Campbell has graciously provided a very good tutorial on getting started here: http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html

What's easier than subscribing to something you want and going about your business?